# view of spinner doesn't gets updated

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner, android-spinner

I am using spinners which are dependent on one another. So when i choose one value in a spinner A the arraylist of other spinners B,C,D change accordingly. 
when I select item at position 1 on spinner B and then choose any other value in spinner A The data on spinner B gets updated. So I again choose item at position 1 on spinner B the view doesn't changes while selecting item at any other position changes the view. So the same index doesn't get updated value in this piece of code.

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapterEmployer = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,employerlist);
    myAdapterEmployer.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    employer.setAdapter(myAdapterEmployer);

    employer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id)
        {
            if(position > 0) {
                employer1 = employer.getSelectedItem().toString();
                employeridname = employdetail.get(employer1);
                Sectorlist(employeridname);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        }


    });
```

This changes data of Sectorlist everytime a item is selected in employer.
And then any item is choosen in sectorlist.

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> myAdaptersector = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sectorlist);
    myAdaptersector.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sector.setAdapter(myAdaptersector);

    sector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id)
        {
            sector1=sector.getSelectedItem().toString();
           String selectedsectortext  = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            if(position > 0){
                sectoridd=sectordetail.get(selectedsectortext);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Here when i choose item at same index as before it doesn't update in the spinner view.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onItemSelected` of the spinner **A** you can set Adapter to other spinners to be update and this will work as you want.

```
 employer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id)
            {
                if(position > 0) {
                    employer1 = employer.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    employeridname = employdetail.get(employer1);
                    Sectorlist(employeridname);

                    // Update other spinners here
                    myAdaptersector = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sectorlist);
                    myAdaptersector.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sector.setAdapter(myAdaptersector);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }  
});
```

Comment: It didn't worked. Gives the same result as earlier. Data on same index is not getting selected.

Comment: Debug sector spinner onItemSelected in that case to see whats happing.